# Quicksort Counter Example

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

Firstly (as the question title implies) I'm not looking for why the bellow partitioning method doesn't work, rather a modification to it so that it will work for the following input:

```java
int[] a = {1,2,8,4,5,7};
```

Here's the `partition` method along with some other stuff:

```java
static int[] swap (int[] a,int i,int j){
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
    return a;
}

static int partition (int[] a,int l,int r){
    int i = l;
    int j = r;
    int v = a[l];
    while (true) {

        while (a[i] < v) {
            if (i == r) break;
            i++;
        }

        while (a[j] > v) {
            if (j == l) break;
            j--;
        }

        if (i >= j) break;

        a = swap(a,i,j);
    }

    a = swap(a, l, j);
    return j;
}

void sort(int[] a,int l,int r){
    int j = partition(a, l, r);
    sort(a, l, j-1);
    sort(a, j+1, r);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = {1,2,8,4,5,7};
    System.out.println(partition(a,0,5));

}
```

Output:

`0`

The output is the index of the pivot returned from the `partition` method. `0`, as the index of the pivot, makes sense in terms of the definition, i.e. `everything left of the pivot is smaller and everything right of the pivot is larger`, but clearly runs into a problem in `sort` namely:

```java
sort(a, l, j-1);
```

where you have the right pointer being negative (`j-1 = 0-1 = -1`). My question again being is there a modification to the above method(s) that will maintain the definition (`everything left of the pivot is smaller and everything right of the pivot is larger`) and not run into the problem in `sort`.

Comment: Add an `if (r < l) return;` to the beginning of `sort`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic your right, I edited `sort`

Comment: Well then, it should work now, shouldn't it? Where is the problem?

Comment: no, as the main problem is with `j-1` being negative (negative array index) for the example I gave since `partition` returns `0` i.e. `j=0`

Comment: Have you tried it? Since -1 is less than 0, that `if` is going to prevent further processing of that index. So it should solve your problem.

Comment: oh right.. sorry I'm stupid. If you post comment as question ill accept it

Comment: Well, you'll need to undo your edit, as the answer will not make sense when that line of code is already in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing part is the line

```
if ( l >= r ) return;
```

in the beginning of the `sort` method. This is actually the recursion stop step so it is necessary to have it anyway to prevent endless recursion. But besides that, it also solves your problem, because if you call `sort(0,-1)` then -1 is less than 0, so it prevents further processing of that index.